# Bash: Kill Process after timeout or after an event

Tags: bash, timeout

I have a script which runs a long running process.
This process is currently stopped after a timeout.

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 3600 ./longrunningprocess
```

My problem is now that this process does not return before the timeout is reached and sometimes I need to stop it earlier.

What do I need?

I want to start some other script in parallel which checks periodically if my longrunningprocess should stop. When this bash script returns, the timeout command should be killed.

Any idea how I could achieve that?

Is there anything like the timeout command? Not with a timespan but a script I could start and which is like the event trigger?

E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
fancyCommandKillsSecondCommandIfFirstCommandReturns "./myPeriodicScript.sh" "timeout 3600 ./longrunningprocess"
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** Something like "Start 2 Processes in parallel and kill both if one returns" would also work...

**Edit2:** The answers gave me some ideas for a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FirstProcess="${1}"
SecondProcess="${2}"

exec $FirstProcess &
PID1=$!
exec $SecondProcess &
PID2=$!

function killall {
    if ps -p $PID1 > /dev/null
    then
        kill -9 $PID1
    fi
    if ps -p $PID2 > /dev/null
    then
        kill -9 $PID2
    fi
}
trap killall EXIT

while true; do
    if ! ps -p $PID1 > /dev/null
    then
       exit;
    fi
    if ! ps -p $PID2 > /dev/null
    then
       exit;
    fi
    sleep 5;
done
```

This kind of does what I want. Is there any native functionality or a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use `crontab` to launch a periodic script checking and killing your job. For the kill itself, I don't know.

Comment: I have to add some information: The script that runs the script which starts the longrunningprocess is running multiple times with different parameters. So a global crontab would be probably no solution because it depends on the current context.
In C# I would probably use CancellationTokens...

Answer (score 0):

Start the longrunningprocess in the background and remember the pid.

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 3600 ./longrunningprocess &
long_pid=$!
./myPeriodicScript.sh
kill -9 ${long_pid}
```

Comment: But what, if my longrunningprocess returns before the timeout?

Comment: The pid will not be reused within a few hours, so you can just ignore (or use `2>/dev/null`) the error message when the pid is gone. When you are in doubt if this works, you can use some `ps` for more information about the long_pid before you want to kill it (check the scriptname, starttime,..) or look hoe you can set the process group id of your script to long_pid (if there exists a process group whose process group ID is equal to that process ID, the process ID shall not be reused by the system until the process group lifetime ends).

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the output of the *longrunningprocess* to determine if the process needs to be killed, then you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FIFO="tmpfifo"
TIMEOUT=10

mkfifo $FIFO

timeout 100 ./longrun &> $FIFO &
PID=$!

while read line; do
    echo "Parsing $line see if $PID needs to be killed";
    if [ "$line" = "5" ]; then
        kill $PID
    fi 
done < $FIFO
exit
```

This will pipe all output into a FIFO and start reading from that fifo. In addition, it keeps the PID of the `timeout` process, so it can be killed.